# Export data from AWS glue to BigQuery

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-bigquery, etl, aws-glue

I have successfully connected to my bigquery using:

`sparkSession.read.format("jdbc").option("url",jdbc_url).option("dbtable","cash_in").option("driver","cdata.jdbc.googlebigquery.GoogleBigQueryDriver").load()`

However I don't want to read data from BigQuery, I want to write from my aurora database to it.

Something like:

`retDatasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = orders, connection_type = "bigquery", connection_options = {"jdbc_url": jdbc_url, "dbtable" : "cash_in", "driver", "cdata.jdbc.googlebigquery.GoogleBigQueryDriver" })`

However te connection_type mysql, postgresql, redshift, sqlserver e oracle. .